# Angular 2 for loop showing error

Tags: angular, loops, for-loop

As you can see from the code, I have a popup window that is showing all users, and users from the current project are checked. This is a ts file:

```
users = [];
projectUsers = [];


constructor( private userService: UserService, private projectService: ProjectService, public dialog: DialogRef<any> ) {
    super( dialog, dialog.context );
}

ngOnInit() {  
    this.projectService.getUsersForProject(this.context.projectId).subscribe(
            (response:any) => {
                this.projectUsers = response 
            },
            error => { console.error( error ); },
        );

    this.userService.get().subscribe(
            response =>  
                this.users = response,
            error => { console.error( error ); },
        );

    }

containsUser (user) {
    for( var u of this.projectUsers) {
        if (u.user.id === user.id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

selectUser(category, event , user) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
        this.projectUsers.push(user);
    } 
    else {
        this.projectUsers.splice(user);
    }
}

submitUser() {
    this.confirm(this.projectUsers);
}
```

}

And this is html part for this:

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users">
    <input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="containsUser(user)"  name="user" (change)="selectUser(option, $event, user)">{{ user.person.name }}
</li>
```

selectUser function should listen for changes and if I am checking any user to add to project it will push it in projectUser array, or splice it if it is unchecked.

Problem is happening in container function and debugger is pointing to (if (u.user.id === user.id)) error with message: cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

That is happening only after I check some user and proceed with function. Does anyone have idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
containsUser (user) {
 if(user) {
  for( var u of this.projectUsers) {
      if (u.user && u.user.id === user.id) {
        return true;
      }
  }
    return false;
 }
}
```

I think you need to do this testing in your if
Cause if you have 'u' or 'user' undefined you will receive a error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is coz of this :

```
this.projectUsers.splice(user);
```

You should read the **[array splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** and what parameters it takes.